# VueJs. В дочернем компоненте хуки created или mounted вызываются дважды

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Когда я пишу в родительском компоненте router-view, в дочернем компоненте хуки created или mounted вызываются дважды

Parent:

```
<template>
  <v-content class="main">
    <Header class="header" />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Tabs :tabs="$store.state.menu.adminItems" router=true />
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </v-content>
</template>
```

Child:

```
  created () {
    console.log('Вызывается дважды')
  }
```

Comment: У вашем компоненте делается запрос на получение данных?

Comment: Да, и по сути проиcходит два запроса к api

Comment: Скорее всего, компонет Child используется в двух разных родительских компонентах, которые одновременно находятся на странице